# Django + twitter bootstrap + github what's the most elegant way to do this?

Tags: python, django, git, twitter-bootstrap

Let's assume that I have a [project](https://github.com/kimvais/nimismies) or [two](https://github.com/kimvais/repokarma) that I'm building with Django and twitter bootsrap. The said projects are versioned in git repositories.

Currently, I, like most people, will (or would) just [download bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), do some `cp -r` and `git add` commands and happily code away.

But now I stopped thinking.

- Everything is on git.
- git supports subrepos.
- Django has `collectstatic`.
- This is 2013 and continuous integration et al. are the buzzwords of the decade

so: **there must be a more elegant and simply *better* way of doing this** as everything I would do would be a horrible violation of **DRY**

Comment: Why not just load Bootstrap from a CDN? http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for because there is an ugly part in this strategy, but it's worth mentionning IMHO.

### Overview

1. **Compile less in debug mode in the browser** for development. This enables your integrator to work faster and to view syntax errors reports in the browser and make development awesome.
2. **Use django-compressor** for production to pre-compile all your less into css and make performance awesome.
3. **Be able to reuse in your less scripts: bootstrap classes, variables**, etc, etc ... else what is less good for ? The problem is that you must get your compiler to compile both bootstrap and your own less scripts in the same run.

### Basic strategy at Django level

This is how your `site_base.html` template could contain:

```
{% if debug %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/style.css' %}" />
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less" charset="utf-8" type="text/less" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">less = {}; less.env = 'development';</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}less.js" ></script>
{% else %}
    {% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/style.css' %}" />
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less" charset="utf-8" type="text/less" rel="stylesheet">
     {% endcompress %}
{% endif %}
```

Ok, that's the ugly part: it's not very DRY ... but it does work really great. As you can see, you need the [debug context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug).

This is how your settings could look like:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'recess --compile {infile} > {outfile}'),
)
```

Note: bootstrap only compiled on recess less compiler when I did this. Maybe other compilers are supported nowadays but I wouldn't bet on it.

### Basic git strategy

To re-use bootstrap directly from their repo, use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

### Basic strategy at the less level

Suppose we create a `custom.less` script which should be able to re-use bootstrap stuff, ie. variables, classes, mixins and so on.

We now have a problem: the compiler must parse both bootstrap's stuff and `custom.less` at the same time. Else, how could the compiler know about bootstrap's variables when compiling `custom.less` ?

So, you could import `custom.less` in `bootstrap.less`, but that will cause a modification of a file outside your repo (remember: bootstrap.less comes from a submodule).

Solution: create a `master.less` which import both `bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` and `custom.less`. Don't forget to link `master.less` instead of `bootstrap.less` in your `site_base.html`.

Answer (score 3):

You can install this app in django and use

```
pip install -U django-staticfiles-bootstrap 
./manage.py collectstatic
```

to pull the latest bootstrap code into your project :)

https://github.com/Apreche/django-staticfiles-bootstrap

Comment: What django-staticfiles-bootstrap did was simply copy -r and git-add bootstrap, it's exactly what the TO complained about but in an external app !!

Comment: ./manage.py collectstatic only needs to be run on production.  when 'django-staticfiles-bootstrap' is added to your INSTALLED_APPS the static files are automatically loaded in the development server.  there is no need to be adding the static assets to your git repo

Comment: I understand that django-staticfiles-bootstrap provides a hard copy of bootstrap. But then, what's the advantage of depending on django-staticfiles-bootstrap over keeping a hard copy by yourself ?